# Some profile users not able to see all queues in Omni supervisor tab

Tags: profile, omnichannel, omni-supervisor, agentwork

Some profile users cannot see all the queues in omni supervisor tab Agent Summary dropdown menu.
But some profile users can see. So I understand here the issue is with profile settings.
But I am not able to find what is the setting is missing.

[image]
Could anyone please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Can you try assigning Manage Users perm as mentioned in [post](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/pt-BR/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A898PSAR)

Comment: yes its already given. only some particular queues are not visible

Comment: I found the reason:
To filter the agents that these supervisors can see in the Agents tab, add at least one public group in the Select Visible Agents section. The members of the public group are the agents that the supervisors can see in Omni Supervisor.

So I added the supervisor into the group and its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is :

> To filter the agents that these supervisors can see in the Agents tab, add at least one public group in the Select Visible Agents section. The members of the public group are the agents that the supervisors can see in Omni Supervisor.

So I added the supervisor into the group and its working now.

Thank you